# My Django Middleware Isn't Working The Way It Should

Tags: django, templates, middleware

How do I go about passing the `reason` to banned.html from the `UserBanning` model from the middleware file? Almost everything works but I can't seem to get the `reason` from the model to display in the template `banned.html` and im unsure way so any help will be amazing just got into learning about middleware. Should I be using `process_request()` instead?

Thanks

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

class UserBanning(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Username", help_text="Choose Username", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ban = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Ban", help_text="Users Bans")
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "User Banning"
        ordering = ('user',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}"
```

middleware.py:

```
from .models import UserBanning
from django.shortcuts import render


class BanManagement():
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        banned = UserBanning.objects.all()
        context = {
            'banned': banned,
        }

        if(banned.filter(ban=True, user_id=request.user.id)):
            return render(request, "account/banned.html", context)
        else:
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

banned.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>Your account has been banned. Reason: {{ banned.reason }}</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost done. The remaining problem is that you need to `filter` on `request.user.id` before you set the `context`, in order for the context to contain this specific user's ban only. Something like:

```
    banned = UserBanning.objects.filter(ban=True, user=request.user)

    if banned:
        context = {'banned': banned[0]}
        return render(request, "account/banned.html", context)
    else:
```

Comment: Hello @krubo so I just found out I am getting this error if the user is signed out and viewing my site. `TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`

Comment: ^ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741959/django-middleware-anonymoususer-object-is-not-iterable