# Django Middleware - 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

Tags: django, middleware

Related question for context/code: [My Django Middleware Isn't Working The Way It Should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58719348/my-django-middleware-isnt-working-the-way-it-should/58719612#58719612)

So I just got help and got my other question related to this one answered but after I added the code I found out now every time a user who isn't signed in views the site they see the error below so any help with be appreciated. Thanks

Error: `'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`

```
C:\Users\...\account\banning\middleware.py in __call__
        if(UserBanning.objects.filter(ban=True, user=request.user)): …
```

middleware.py:

```
from .models import UserBanning
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


class BanManagement():
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if(UserBanning.objects.filter(ban=True, user=request.user)):
            context = {
                'banned': banned[0],
            }
            return render(request, "account/banned.html", context)
        else:
            response = self.get_response(request)
            return response
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

class UserBanning(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Username", help_text="Choose Username", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ban = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Ban", help_text="Users Bans")
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "User Banning"
        ordering = ('user',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code like this:

```
def __call__(self, request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        banned = UserBanning.objects.filter(ban=True, user=request.user)
        if banned.exists():
            context = {
                'banned': banned[0],
            }
            return render(request, "account/banned.html", context)

    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
```

### Explanation

I am checking if user [**`is_authenticated`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) or not. If not authenticated, then there is no point for checking banned or not. Then I am querying through `UserBanning` model to check if the user [**`exists()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#exists).

Comment: Now when a user is signed in I am getting this error `list index out of range` because of `'banned': banned[0],`